# Designed memory unit doesn't work, cannot read memory 0

Tags: verilog, modelsim

```
module InstructionMemory (input clk,
                          input[31:0] PC, 
                          output reg[31:0] Inst_out
                        );

  reg[31:0] instructions [0:2**32-1];

  initial 
    $readmemb("InstructionMemory.txt",instructions);

  always@(posedge clk)
  begin 
    Inst_out = instructions[PC]; 
  end

endmodule
```

This is my InstructionMemory.txt's text:

> 00000000000000010000000011110000

Comment: Show us your testbench, please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assumed that, 
You have typo at

> reg[31:0] instructions [0: 2**32 -1];

It should be,

> reg[31:0] instructions [0: (2*32) -1];

Because `2**32 = 4294967296`, It can not be this much long.

After that I modified your `InstructionMemory.txt` file and run the simulation it works fine, see below code.

Verilog Code with Testbench:

```
module InstructionMemory (input clk,
                          input[31:0] PC, 
                          output reg[31:0] Inst_out
                        );

  reg [31:0] instructions [0 : (2*32) -1];
  initial 
  begin
    $readmemb("InstructionMemory.txt",instructions);
  end

  always@(posedge clk)
  begin 
    Inst_out <= instructions[PC]; 
  end

endmodule

module tb;
reg clk;
reg [31:0] PC;
wire [31:0] Inst_out;
integer j;

InstructionMemory InstructionMemory_u0(clk, PC, Inst_out);

always #5 clk = ~clk;

initial
begin
  $monitor("PC = %d and Inst_Out = %d", PC, Inst_out);
  clk = 1'b0;
  PC = 32'b0;
  for(j=0;j<64;j=j+1)
  begin
    @(posedge clk) 
    PC = j;
  end
  #100 $finish;
end


endmodule
```

Your memory `InstructionMemory.txt`

```
00000000000000000000000000000000
00000000000000000000000000000001
00000000000000000000000000000010
00000000000000000000000000000011
00000000000000000000000000000100
00000000000000000000000000000101
00000000000000000000000000000110
00000000000000000000000000000111
00000000000000000000000000001000
00000000000000000000000000001001
00000000000000000000000000001010
00000000000000000000000000001011
00000000000000000000000000001100
00000000000000000000000000001101
00000000000000000000000000001110
00000000000000000000000000001111
00000000000000000000000000010000
00000000000000000000000000010001
00000000000000000000000000010010
00000000000000000000000000010011
00000000000000000000000000010100
00000000000000000000000000010101
00000000000000000000000000010110
00000000000000000000000000010111
00000000000000000000000000011000
00000000000000000000000000011001
00000000000000000000000000011010
00000000000000000000000000011011
00000000000000000000000000011100
00000000000000000000000000011101
00000000000000000000000000011110
00000000000000000000000000011111
00000000000000000000000000100000
00000000000000000000000000100001
00000000000000000000000000100010
00000000000000000000000000100011
00000000000000000000000000100100
00000000000000000000000000100101
00000000000000000000000000100110
00000000000000000000000000100111
00000000000000000000000000101000
00000000000000000000000000101001
00000000000000000000000000101010
00000000000000000000000000101011
00000000000000000000000000101100
00000000000000000000000000101101
00000000000000000000000000101110
00000000000000000000000000101111
00000000000000000000000000110000
00000000000000000000000000110001
00000000000000000000000000110010
00000000000000000000000000110011
00000000000000000000000000110100
00000000000000000000000000110101
00000000000000000000000000110110
00000000000000000000000000110111
00000000000000000000000000111000
00000000000000000000000000111001
00000000000000000000000000111010
00000000000000000000000000111011
00000000000000000000000000111100
00000000000000000000000000111101
00000000000000000000000000111110
00000000000000000000000000111111
```

Simulation:

```
QuestaSim-64 qverilog 10.4 Compiler 2014.12 Dec  2 2014
Start time: 10:18:08 on May 16,2016
qverilog mem.v 
-- Compiling module InstructionMemory
-- Compiling module tb

Top level modules:
    tb
Reading pref.tcl

# 10.4

# vsim -lib work tb -c -do "run -all; quit -f" -appendlog -l qverilog.log -vopt 
# ** Note: (vsim-8009) Loading existing optimized design _opt1
# //  Questa Sim-64
# //  Version 10.4 linux_x86_64 Dec  2 2014
# //
# //  Copyright 1991-2014 Mentor Graphics Corporation
# //  All Rights Reserved.
# //
# //  THIS WORK CONTAINS TRADE SECRET AND PROPRIETARY INFORMATION
# //  WHICH IS THE PROPERTY OF MENTOR GRAPHICS CORPORATION OR ITS
# //  LICENSORS AND IS SUBJECT TO LICENSE TERMS.
# //  THIS DOCUMENT CONTAINS TRADE SECRETS AND COMMERCIAL OR FINANCIAL
# //  INFORMATION THAT ARE PRIVILEGED, CONFIDENTIAL, AND EXEMPT FROM
# //  DISCLOSURE UNDER THE FREEDOM OF INFORMATION ACT, 5 U.S.C. SECTION 552.
# //  FURTHERMORE, THIS INFORMATION IS PROHIBITED FROM DISCLOSURE UNDER
# //  THE TRADE SECRETS ACT, 18 U.S.C. SECTION 1905.
# //
# Loading work.tb(fast)
# run -all
# PC =          0 and Inst_Out =          x
# PC =          0 and Inst_Out =          0
# PC =          1 and Inst_Out =          0
# PC =          2 and Inst_Out =          1
# PC =          3 and Inst_Out =          2
# PC =          4 and Inst_Out =          3
# PC =          5 and Inst_Out =          4
# PC =          6 and Inst_Out =          5
# PC =          7 and Inst_Out =          6
# PC =          8 and Inst_Out =          7
# PC =          9 and Inst_Out =          8
# PC =         10 and Inst_Out =          9
# PC =         11 and Inst_Out =         10
# PC =         12 and Inst_Out =         11
# PC =         13 and Inst_Out =         12
# PC =         14 and Inst_Out =         13
# PC =         15 and Inst_Out =         14
# PC =         16 and Inst_Out =         15
# PC =         17 and Inst_Out =         16
# PC =         18 and Inst_Out =         17
# PC =         19 and Inst_Out =         18
# PC =         20 and Inst_Out =         19
# PC =         21 and Inst_Out =         20
# PC =         22 and Inst_Out =         21
# PC =         23 and Inst_Out =         22
# PC =         24 and Inst_Out =         23
# PC =         25 and Inst_Out =         24
# PC =         26 and Inst_Out =         25
# PC =         27 and Inst_Out =         26
# PC =         28 and Inst_Out =         27
# PC =         29 and Inst_Out =         28
# PC =         30 and Inst_Out =         29
# PC =         31 and Inst_Out =         30
# PC =         32 and Inst_Out =         31
# PC =         33 and Inst_Out =         32
# PC =         34 and Inst_Out =         33
# PC =         35 and Inst_Out =         34
# PC =         36 and Inst_Out =         35
# PC =         37 and Inst_Out =         36
# PC =         38 and Inst_Out =         37
# PC =         39 and Inst_Out =         38
# PC =         40 and Inst_Out =         39
# PC =         41 and Inst_Out =         40
# PC =         42 and Inst_Out =         41
# PC =         43 and Inst_Out =         42
# PC =         44 and Inst_Out =         43
# PC =         45 and Inst_Out =         44
# PC =         46 and Inst_Out =         45
# PC =         47 and Inst_Out =         46
# PC =         48 and Inst_Out =         47
# PC =         49 and Inst_Out =         48
# PC =         50 and Inst_Out =         49
# PC =         51 and Inst_Out =         50
# PC =         52 and Inst_Out =         51
# PC =         53 and Inst_Out =         52
# PC =         54 and Inst_Out =         53
# PC =         55 and Inst_Out =         54
# PC =         56 and Inst_Out =         55
# PC =         57 and Inst_Out =         56
# PC =         58 and Inst_Out =         57
# PC =         59 and Inst_Out =         58
# PC =         60 and Inst_Out =         59
# PC =         61 and Inst_Out =         60
# PC =         62 and Inst_Out =         61
# PC =         63 and Inst_Out =         62
# PC =         63 and Inst_Out =         63
# ** Note: $finish    : mem.v(39)
#    Time: 735 ns  Iteration: 0  Instance: /tb
# End time: 10:18:09 on May 16,2016, Elapsed time: 0:00:01
# Errors: 0, Warnings: 0
```

> Your output is **one cycle late** due to flop used in Reading of Instruction.

If you really want to use 2**32 set of instruction, you have to declare memory for the same.

Edit:

Information about PC,
Let's take example of 8051, a real ***uController***, where you find PC size 16 bits long. so it can access program addresses 0x0000 to 0xFFFF, a total of 64K bytes of code. However, not all members of the 8051 have the entire 64K bytes of on-chip ROM installed. It is for ***expandable memory usage***.

Comment: Thank you for your on note answer. I have a question, is declaring my memory address digits as 32 bits , enough? My PC is 32 bits long, so I assume that my instruction memory must have been the same.